# Program hangs when using multiprocessing module

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I've got a huge amount of data to parse so the results can be used to build Python class instances. Naturally, I turned to the Python multiprocessing module to harness all 36 cores. Unfortunately, the program halts indefinitely after I assume all processes have carried out their jobs. I've added print statements to track where the interpreter is, and the child processes aren't "ending". The program sits, and the final print in the `buildPopulation` method after the multiprocessing operations is not carried out.

Here is an example...

The file containing the **main** function:

```
from Engines.ReadRecords.ClinicalIOEngineClass import *

def buildPopulation():
    #lots of code in serial here....
    numCores = 36

    #code "breaks" somewhere in here....
    allPatients2 = clinicalIOEngine.addClinicalData(allPatients, "headache_migraine_medcodes", tuple(headacheMedcodeDF[ClinicalIOEngine.MEDCODE_STR]), numCores)

    print("I never get here.....")
    #lots of code in serial here....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    studySpace = buildPopulation()
```

The file containing the class code (and multiprocessing code) looks similar to this:

```
import multiprocessing

class ClinicalIOEngine(IOEngine):

    CLINICAL_FILE_FOLDER_STR = "D:\CPRD_DATA\CLINICAL"
    
    def __init__(self, clinicalDirLocStr):
        IOEngine.__init__(self, clinicalDirLocStr)
```

This method does all the processing once a process has been forked. It has a reference to a queue so items can be added and shared once all child processes have finished.

```
    def addClinicalDataToPatient(self, patients, clinicalTagStr, medcodeTuple, queue):

        newPatientList = []
        for patient in patients:
            patidStr = patient.getPatid()
            indDF = self.ioDF[self.ioDF["patid"] == patidStr]

            if indDF.empty:
                newPatientList.append(patient)
                continue
            else:
                clinicalList = []
                for index, row in indDF.iterrows():
                    medcodeStr = row["medcode"]
                    if medcodeTuple is None:
                        constypeStr = row["constype"]
                        considStr = row["consid"]
                        eventdateStr = row["eventdate"]
                        enttypeStr = row["enttype"]
                        if pd.isna(eventdateStr) or pd.isna(constypeStr) or pd.isna(considStr) or pd.isna(enttypeStr):
                            continue
                        clinicalEntity = Clinical(eventdateStr, considStr, constypeStr, medcodeStr, enttypeStr)
                        clinicalList.append(clinicalEntity)
                    else:
                        if medcodeStr in medcodeTuple:
                            constypeStr = row["constype"]
                            considStr = row["consid"]
                            eventdateStr = row["eventdate"]
                            enttypeStr = row["enttype"]
                            if pd.isna(eventdateStr) or pd.isna(constypeStr) or pd.isna(considStr) or pd.isna(enttypeStr):
                                continue
                            clinicalEntity = Clinical(eventdateStr, considStr, constypeStr, medcodeStr, enttypeStr)
                            clinicalList.append(clinicalEntity)
                if not clinicalList:
                    print(" ".join(["...no clinical data:", clinicalTagStr]))
                else:
                    print(" ".join(["...adding clinical data:", clinicalTagStr]))
                if clinicalList:
                    patient.addClinicalList(clinicalTagStr, clinicalList)
                    newPatientList.append(patient)

        queue.put(newPatientList)
```

After object instantiation, this method is called to start the multiprocessing...

```
    def addClinicalData(self, patients, clinicalTagStr, medcodeTuple=None, numCores=1):
        patientsList = patients.getAllPatients()
        splitList = list(np.array_split(patientsList, numCores))

        queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

        with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
            workers = []
            for i in range(numCores):
                workers.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=self.addClinicalDataToPatient,
                                                       args=(splitList[i], clinicalTagStr, medcodeTuple, queue)))

            for worker in workers:
                worker.start()
            for worker in workers:
                worker.join()                    

        newPatients = Patients()
        for i in range(numCores):
            patientList = queue.get()
            for patient in patientList:
                newPatients.addPatient(patient)

        return newPatients
```

Comment: I believe you need to retrieve all the items from the queue before `worker.join()` will return.

Comment: This isn't really a good use of queue. Just have the subprocesses return results and use them directly.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks, @jasonharper - I'm fairly new to Python but I understand the concept. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @CJR Could you add a positive example? I'm very new to Python's multiprocessing capabilities.

Comment: Just move the `queue.get()` loop up a bit, so it's between the `worker.start()` and `worker.join()` loops.

Comment: No, without an example that I can run I can't change it to show you what I mean. I would use a process pool and pool.map for this problem. You don't need more complexity than that.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper, massively appreciated. I'll give it a try.